# Following update of ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10, conky doesn't move with workspace ruining transparent background illusion

Tags: conky

I recently upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. I am using the default Unity desktop environment. Prior to the update, when I switched workspaces, my conky and icons would move with the desktop off the screen and there would be identical conky and icons on the new desktop. Now, they stay in place on the screen.

This ruins the illusion of the conky having a transparent background, since now when I switch workspaces, I see the wallpaper moving everywhere except behind the conky. Is there any way to fix this? Either by having the conky move with the desktop, or having the backgroud of the conky move too?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't updated to these 16 versions. Even newer one may have bugs. That's why i don't. My recommendation is to reinstall your old Ubuntu.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Adding

```
own_window_argb_visual yes
```

to he config file fixed the problem